# VBA - Excel: How can I optimize this code?

Tags: excel, vba, optimization

For a long time I'm not playing with VBA, so we have a spreadsheet on my work and checkng its code, I'm sure it can be improved.

Basically this spreadsheet has literally 200 buttons (100 to open and another 100 to close) and it copies the data from one sheet to another. Below are the examples of two of this macros.

Macro #1:

```
Sub IT100stop()
'
' newstop Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+s
'
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("G47").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "DOWN"
    
    
    Range("H47").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=YEAR(TODAY())&MONTH(TODAY())&DAY(TODAY())&HOUR(NOW())&MINUTE(NOW())&SECOND(NOW())"
    Range("H47").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("j47").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NOW()"
    Range("j47").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Range("K47").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="""","""",IF(NOW()-RC[-1]<1,HOUR(NOW()-RC[-1])&"" h ""&MINUTE(NOW()-RC[-1])&"" m"",IF(DAYS(NOW(),RC[-1])<2,DAYS(NOW(),RC[-1])&"" day"",DAYS(NOW(),RC[-1])&"" days"")))"

    Range("F47").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Macro #2:

```
Sub IT100released()
'
' newreleased Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Sheets("Database").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Sheets("SINOPTIC").Select
    Range("F47:U47").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Database").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
        xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("SINOPTIC").Select
    Range("G47").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "OK"
    Range("H47:U47").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The question is: what can we do to improve this code? If I add this following code before and after the actual macro code, will the calculations be faster?

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Macro Code

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application. DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Avoid `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: `Range("j47").Value = Now()` should simplify, instead of entering `=NOW()` as a formula and then copy/pasting values.

Comment: `Range("H47").Value = Format$(Now(),"yyyymdhms")`.

Comment: and `Range("H47").Value = FORMAT(Now(),"yyyymmddhhmmss")`

Comment: If you have that code x 100 then I would start with that part...

Comment: Thanks a lot guys... on Macro #1, I added your comments and the code is much more elegant.

What about Macro #2 when I have to copy and paste from one side to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to what BigBen wrote: avoid the Select; that is the code created by the macro recorder, but it performs many unnecessary operations.
This is the "human" version of your macro # 2

```
Sub IT100released()
'
' newreleased Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+r
'
    With Application
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        Sheets("Database").Rows("2:2").Insert shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Sheets("SINOPTIC").Range("F47:U47").Copy
        Sheets("Database").Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
        Sheets("SINOPTIC").Range("G47") = "OK"
        Sheets("SINOPTIC").Range("H47:U47").ClearContents
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Great... now with the second example I got the whole idea with the "SELECT".

Thanks a million.